# Знаки препинания. Просьба помочь с расстановкой

Tags: пунктуация

В последнее время я очень грустный и знаете это очень мешает мне сосредоточиться на повседневных делах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***В последнее время я очень грустный, и, знаете, это очень мешает мне сосредоточиться на повседневных делах.***

ССП, состоящее из двух неоднородных предложений, у которых нет общего, объединяющего члена, поэтому перед союзом **и** *здесь **нужно поставить запятую***. Вводное слово *знаете* **обособляется запятыми**.

http://newslab.ru/article/265784

Answer (score 5):

1) **В последнее время** я очень грустный и мне трудно сосредоточиться на повседневных делах.

Здесь общее обстоятельство, запятую можно не ставить.

2) **В последнее время** я очень грустный, и, **знаете**, **это** очень мешает мне сосредоточиться на повседневных делах.

Обстоятельство осталось, **но его сложно отнести ко второму предложению** по двум причинам: 1) появилось вводное слово, 2) местоимение "это" отсылает нас к первому предложению.

**Поэтому два предложения уже не объединяются в одну фразу, делается пауза, ставится запятая.**

Answer (score 2):

Возможный вариант:

> *В последнее время я очень грустный. **И знаете,** это очень мешает мне сосредоточиться на повседневных делах.*

В этом варианте запятой после *"и"* не требуется.

См. [**ПАС:**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/#id-7%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%C2%A795)

> **§ 95.** <…> Не отделяются запятой вводные слова от союзов, стоящих в начале предложения:
>
> ***И действительно,*** он скоро уехал;
>
> ***А между прочим,*** магазин уже был закрыт;
>
> ***И в самом деле,*** послышались голоса внизу (Ч.);
>
> ***И пожалуй,*** он правильно поступил.